# Number of surjections

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, set-theory

### Task

Given 2 positive integers `n` and `k`, where `n > k`, output the number of surjections from a set of `n` distinguishable elements to a set of `k` distinguishable elements.

### Definition

A function f: S → T is called a surjection if for every t∈T there is s∈S such that f(s) = t.

### Example

When `n=3` and `k=2`, the output is `6`, since there are `6` surjections from `{1,2,3}` to `{1,2}`:

1. `1↦1, 2↦1, 3↦2`
2. `1↦1, 2↦2, 3↦1`
3. `1↦1, 2↦2, 3↦2`
4. `1↦2, 2↦1, 3↦1`
5. `1↦2, 2↦1, 3↦2`
6. `1↦2, 2↦2, 3↦1`

### Testcases

```
n k output
5 3 150
8 4 40824
9 8 1451520
```

### Reference

- [OEIS A019538](https://oeis.org/A019538)

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins.

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

Comment: A definition of surjection would be nice.

Comment: Is it intentional that **n** cannot equal **k**?

Comment: @Dennis I like to exclude every possible edge case from my challenges

Comment: That seems like an important edge case to include. My guess is that most answers that work for n>k will also work for n==k but it might allow for some sneaky golfing somewhere

Comment: @ whoever voted to close what is your reason?

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
ṗṬML
```

This is an **O(k<sup>n</sup>)** brute force solution.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//4bmX4bmsTUz/OyLDpy/igqxH//9bMywgNV0sIFs0LCA4XQ)

#### How it works

```
ṗṬML  Main link. Left argument: k. Right argument: n.

ṗ     Cartesian power; yield the list of all n-tuples over {1, ..., k}.
      Each tuple represents a (not necessarily surjective) function from
      {1, ..., n} to {1, ..., k}.
 Ṭ    Apply the "untruth" atom to each tuple.
      Ṭ maps a list of indices to an array with 1's at those indices, and exactly
      as many zeroes as needed to build the array.
      Examples:
           [1, 2, 3, 3, 3] -> [1, 1, 1]
           [1, 3, 5]       -> [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
           [2, 6, 2, 4, 4] -> [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
  M   Yield all indices of maximal elements, i.e., all indices of [1] * k.
   L  Take the length.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 48 bytes

```hs
s(_,1)=1
s(1,_)=0
s(m,n)=n*(s(m-1,n-1)+s(m-1,n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcuxCoAgEADQvS/xSqWbWvJLRERCSNKjsjb/3QTb3vJ2lw8fY62ZWY6gcMgMuQU1NyROoGhkTQI5CYTpJ0BNLpDK/no9bV6fd6BH91JoFRqlTMaU1LkYUz8)

#### Why is the surjection count `s(m,n)=n*s(m-1,n-1)+n*s(m-1,n)`?

in order to harvest `n` images, i can either

- squeeze a singleton `[m]` creation into any of
  the `n` boundaries surrounding `n-1` groups
- or add my new `m` into any of `n` already existing groups of `[1..m-1]`

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 38 bytes

```hs
m#n|n<2=1|m<2=0|o<-m-1=n*(o#(n-1)+o#n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1c5rybPxsjWsCYXSBrU5Nvo5uoa2uZpaeQra@TpGmpq5yvnaf7PTczMsy1OLSxNzUtOjS4oyswriYZo1Y021NPLjY0F6gczLWNj/wMA)

Comment: 38 bytes by using an infix operator: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jco7CoAwDADQ3Wtk8UOLmVzMSUooIgGlJqjVzbtXxO0Nb5lykm0rJQISVgiR@krBnjQ6dUjW1glqc9h0CawpOq1GWY5bbJawn6td4es2uoDeK/OjPwfm8gI "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/), 66 bytes

```
def s:_->nat->nat|(m+1)(n+1):=(n+1)*(s m n+s m(n+1))|0 0:=1|_ _:=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lNzPv/PyU1TaHYKl7XLi@xBEzUaORqG2pq5AEJK1swpaVRrJCrkKcNJMF8zRoDBQMrW8OaeIV4K1uD/8qpZYk5CsUKpgrGXDC2hYIJnG2pYPEfAA)

---

### Proof of correctness

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1Rq9buPIuddTTOFFyF2e1lJpn665RtctkHIhELREWoxISiZpr2ivgQAXHC6pggCXpLsUKRIgDxAgXdLfQ/hFNt/PzHCGHEry7l6AyIBFcb6Z7/9vZrI4Kj6k@W5b1mIV1dE4vrlN7/gxSQv9UDe7@MMqTkR1EX7xVRHV9O@9l7@a@F4B/y5m9PXSq0Quilfwn37778/F@cVs8j4U4cXs/ENaVHVULGMBs8ereJmuoqssDq/ifVrVVZjVwivEBY76wnsDTz/9RWzEl6IIxJtyu/PFxUiIp@9/Ld7OYRAfCrEOhF4JJ8Ebf2G9e/r@W4bjQXExG13F12kBa6XF6nZZp9sCRt6l9Rq@vplfwuu63F6KMq7i@psA4B5EvI@WtUirMImyChb96V/i6ce/hQGuGz79@PeAeCq2NXAR3sflVoSI6xFnL6MqrmBhmrVhSjbAKkwA4Op2uQy3CXK/9n0mY81Ir5qQ5@6AXaTemlPFWSIKH0EtCuvyNkbiCqbJBg/EDqhlunBWtNtljeaL3woWgFhv1O@SyVhvmDxYfAOcbyb4b4rcSzgGM7GmCXIWbsswvhlPcI7kcGMsr4hvV1YLK0IRprq9qmoaY@gdwohH/EMgzQnyjy8U0Qdo5oV4yKGOFngUF6vRaMB@pfmixzyg/T795odHtl98VYin7/7A9gsYyXLbqbsyXok3C/MdG2yKRpKSsbbQQBbIkwGkHUm2gER/BM9slh1G8ZV@Sy/UAIO7x3rroBhGGAWAKzLxMM7SXDx8DdT/EkLIy0fJ8Tlx/DXSDgj2gSDbGhP0Wc9P9mAW@/G0Xbq6zYUHYURFggvh4aq5ePrdDyxRXzz99lt6BLhX@BtQPYh6Gya3MG0mGC0sNC5j0GYh9mRF6H8NcdaMJ1rjW7ZQ@B@LZjyVJIK4o9UqLNPrdY1BjSRsL4K49UIIDMvQV5zUtFKOkwKKM3c2aWki0BCQ9y9FTuvW67ggktMiw9X3uPIchY6jMUYdHi3lqPhC5CYTXQrOpOdU6@07gbR6cpKPOFFuyreScptzbMHJ4GdSGmeCjQ7VdV2LuT@umhz08Md/osakDyGuEBi05U6@15P8VSMqyDfiLUhnccl4QY2QdxDNXXwjyiSzxLyO7mIS1b//weK@izIk31gL6SZzzOKF4qgdnbfqQcaW6L8ZCWhxqYAH6KAggvq32VPJQ7Tx2dClCqwrRA855J14u0qTcLcFKGAZ3yoiOfr08LbBubNGEV/31uCoZ61hA@Dkvma9jmIX4hHDYbGCb@2Iu3K7cnvif/7kcMSXg45I9joF@YDNARhICm17GWVLpQH49CDgeaLHZ/IdIIH3CnYCJIGmo2VYxklGwOPxGIj6qwUuGWAfjVsPwWWmItTzZuQivLJPcy8EpC0yeo4KlB3y2wyye2ihyyU4AsE4osEvDh8hUaMcphcMtI0X4itxbjklLgemQ7qKOV6e4ay5NnRnPD0j@6d8OZduBrzyHE9Gj9dYDJDTr9I7nC1TteQOvX1quDl85MQXQlYW@RYDDoKqONeJBTghEA2nlc/KZENMzikUNYoztNdxvK8hmUhybd8665ocCKMxbc5HoRjjM8LzWprcxLAi1C2JDc2IpCWnsRmd6wmgB/BAJWWmJaPsYE1oV6dIBijwleT/2Vy8cHDxwvICpB/Vh0Vhy0Ro0dRomhDSJF2bhCM6dolV8xEriIDwyBhTcRVBCuXKAfoH6Bg4qjyIxKon@On1awG@QzU7OGP5qxgewbASqAKHQk@6ClxzwnTldMiEJp1TCwG1ZHqXRpk71bF5r/dk312@ddwYKfuFUeKXIrAyc1lqcA2C0QXWc@UdNGbAlRAu8GxsycaECCgHm5d4tA6MAm3fkTdh8YygriXvFRT5huUvAZ6thQ5BTqFbRWIW16Z4ESqBcMSKaRO@FBkWZ0Lm5IHy0l2pOOj6eQRPeYPogUTZFTwVsSDVnuGrgY83/5MEb8EAXyCxAUHngzXfCZJ8PqpWftHt3lWJKHuEesRrxZZrgRWHBIbtxEN/zjEbf/SxQCVFDenp6BLH@xWZHzwdkODhXvcN90bfYH6ohwAYTwr2XvUQPk2g4qY3SU4ro7SKqYntz3bMoYYEgJyogPugrZeUSh2gU9Xf9JZu0x9/mP88qpdr1fNAcF6ut/U2b0ggXLphs99b8b3YltRXzVHaMrhgGwie3ci2t5nageZ@oEWcO6O2KvBUGLI/Gptjk0Hi7@YP3cAAAFEHIgtaJS1cgpNslsJT7GJBLrHnju2g/DDq@SlYSonlZKlCCzqRlSc2JECQjBRcf2Ltc@aQoTCVIWXPq8jmT4Q@F633BzTBZeiEGkoAxG4SyAHfgMo/qWof3wRO7FSqYlXamkVaYttBxnfmMhW1XYe1D7wxuYVlfLPA7VI4BQrRjzxNow8l2f0R8vqd7i9sygblFvx8VovOPnVaEvSb1rbKcKTjENWNH4cixQnmeN8zkRM47nG44K0x35lbVcgbdD7CL3mlbb2AuPTaaLxBxR9ZpruBRFtENOf7P7cxQ0mJs80JAtq3AgJX11s63qEN3mbSZgsvqoCeWKyBuYZ3bVqMBr6hGTOc0dLZ26REOudAo3N8XJdRUdmhBJS3zOKoFGD20OlSMmkfL9UW86Xaj2bqHHtwmTRU3spbUz1iq23vc849ZgG@kZFJgyqndtdyJqO1Mxkdx2nlXSOVY6zpIJbh5xkRmzYcJ7QtMsAJBaueSWEgKSVvXMKLtV16aPOYDEp8dorEO93GXPYadjRbT3qlTx//YTxK/wd1ORST19CJ6W0Cwu5Yyjx94R1Tl6eCWK9jauhPIHrAG7vWHCpRHnFQDCQG0Y3fibp6KhBextU2g9acU6R3@CDJ75YJpnI2HDwcDq@9fEI7q3iGFBk@b6f2kOPUyFlBKGFotk/2@E625U0ioEQHHgvAkWRXnIPacvBSlWx8XNOpFN0q7SuTfLY5Ual8jDJQ6zeuGuz/V9VQLH42batCct0rJBu1dWsQO7lsSzs7VHRTAUjK/1S7Wch8N7ybyxsh7RmIOvRNzDNglSX12a2E4aNYSJhJSyifYLR7t@1ItcvSOsCTXyTxsR0gLgLzXKQ9@JHggdqe2Zgi6bFvDurTHPYNKLzkYdO@W3U/mMc6C1u9ild5VG4ec2u@uH5EQ1p0xxznOc7pj5@EVZ2Z9xmyZXni0qcSzdiHD@SCT2SrO0YVYFqnd2nddMfUnQPrIGzdJUBIY2JYY0e4vXdg3pgw2ih1MOggvGeF5OgGAI9vxtPeyKk2ygqVBtpdRIgy3mXRMsZbGBjMQXF3rDkse2zId@Lpu98jYNRJS1IzAVPbHR2IsM4F1OWPRwf9aI8O@gepYlN04hkdVeph6lr6jBBX/m9CnB1nDoW4jm0FAs3IyRjpxJa5tK0EOj/r0sy0kxn5xktqY@656uTk0KucWCYhlPVIbhAc3ZO3UhEXAHuBXTjXAArNyjwUty5WYdvtbdQ@sA9i7bffx3v4TlYQu4Xtz@2vvtYOBDlN6Q1VOvqCQWsG4u3NwqVMPTbqFjQoRaMCo@O/wwWYL6yALk@WTZewMsizmLc5NC9R8Lp6vOSQZ@gGzZPinrjBmkUVZM8ox7SYQIKd9KH95KDlupNfTx2IybjKcpwPuSmZPKu0fOinITvek@oPbUr2JsrbIy7LoLjcmyHzHsY0aAN66VRd3ZOtQMt1t/ueW7f/zDCB4g3E/AQ19Cbbb7pXY@SO6VD949Kqwtu/wmBDSb109AXrpUXslkbYbUaOlULOquLlM4WEIplPXFPRDbfARbRK@cZsZY@zYksOJM7bHNCUgmFM6Vjct6unzxmtIN91wtVBwanqZT4Q4FQeUmeRyy0UM8u6iKtK3kHO8T6MPMrN1Z2oZ59G8mVJ6eryFDCnXXF520Zv6hTWxQkJYZ7tFz72y7iaSNeO6Z55Hg2qIPUUwQjvlegzadXRI0D7o6DDT@KwdwDbigDe4be6TuDzxW1P3ykLRchXCUd8fergYr6@9@k5FqUb62NcFc3zGuyP33DB6TNSvFF6As6H56iMzo9bk/m4g@TTWOCfwIQaR6369KWlobkCQg4cO8ujdBCrcZvZPliX9/0/yoLl3DF1Erd02@fM8hhCXK/jbRnn5kA47VDBdjRT1ID5lquPIol3U7qEhbSe1yHN592QD/8F)

---

### Explanation

Let us ungolf the function:

```
def s : nat->nat->nat
| (m+1) (n+1) := (n+1)*(s m n + s m (n+1))
| 0     0     := 1
| _     _     := 0
```

The function is defined by pattern matching and recursion, both of which have built-in support.

We define `s(m+1, n+1) = (n+1) * (s(m, n) + s(m, n+1)` and `s(0, 0) = 1`, which leaves open `s(m+1, 0)` and `s(0, n+1)`, both of which are defined to be `0` by the last case.

Lean uses lamdba calculus syntax, so `s m n` is `s(m, n)`.

---

Now, the proof of correctness: I stated it in two ways:

```
def correctness : ∀ m n, fin (s m n) ≃ { f : fin m → fin n // function.surjective f } :=
λ m, nat.rec_on m (λ n, nat.cases_on n s_zero_zero (λ n, s_zero_succ n)) $
λ m ih n, nat.cases_on n (s_succ_zero m) $ λ n,
calc fin (s (nat.succ m) (nat.succ n))
   ≃ (fin (n + 1) × (fin (s m n + s m (n + 1)))) :
  (fin_prod _ _).symm
... ≃ (fin (n + 1) × (fin (s m n) ⊕ fin (s m (n + 1)))) :
  equiv.prod_congr (equiv.refl _) (fin_sum _ _).symm
... ≃ (fin (n + 1) × ({f : fin m → fin n // function.surjective f} ⊕
         {f : fin m → fin (n + 1) // function.surjective f})) :
  equiv.prod_congr (equiv.refl _) (equiv.sum_congr (ih n) (ih (n + 1)))
... ≃ {f // function.surjective f} : s_aux m n

def correctness_2 (m n : nat) : s m n = fintype.card { f : fin m → fin n // function.surjective f } :=
by rw fintype.of_equiv_card (correctness m n); simp
```

The first one is what is really going on: a bijection between `[0 ... s(m, n)-1]` and the surjections from `[0 ... m-1]` onto `[0 ... n-1]`.

The second one is how it is usually stated, that `s(m, n)` is the cardinality of the surjections from `[0 ... m-1]` onto `[0 ... n-1]`.

---

Lean uses type theory as its foundation (instead of set theory). In type theory, every object has a type that is inherent to it. `nat` is the type of natural numbers, and the statement that `0` is a natural number is expressed as `0 : nat`. We say that `0` is of type `nat`, and that `nat` has `0` as an inhabitant.

Propositions (statements / assertions) are also types: their inhabitant is a proof of the proposition.

---

- `def`: We are going to introduce a definition (because a bijection is really a function, not just a proposition).
- `correctness`: the name of the definition
- `∀ m n`: for every `m` and `n` (Lean automatically infers that their type is `nat`, because of what follows).
- `fin (s m n)` is the type of natural numbers that is smaller than `s m n`. To make an inhabitant, one provides a natural number and a proof that it is smaller than `s m n`.
- `A ≃ B`: bijection between the type `A` and the type `B`. Saying bijection is misleading, as one actually has to provide the inverse function.
- `{ f : fin m → fin n // function.surjective f }` the type of surjections from `fin m` to `fin n`. This syntax builds a subtype from the type `fin m → fin n`, i.e. the type of functions from `fin m` to `fin n`. The syntax is `{ var : base type // proposition about var }`.
- `λ m` : `∀ var, proposition / type involving var` is really a function that takes `var` as an input, so `λ m` introduces the input. `∀ m n,` is short-hand for `∀ m, ∀ n,`
- `nat.rec_on m`: do recursion on `m`. To define something for `m`, define the thing for `0` and then given the thing for `k`, build the thing for `k+1`. One would notice that this is similar to induction, and indeed this is a result of the [Church-Howard correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence). The syntax is `nat.rec_on var (thing when var is 0) (for all k, given "thing when k is k", build thing when var is "k+1")`.

Heh, this is getting long and I'm only on the third line of `correctness`...

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 19 bytes

```
-/@(^~*]!0{])],i.@-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/3X1HTTi6rRiFQ2qYzVjdTL1HHT/a3Ip6Smop4EUqeso1FoppBVzcaUmZ@QrxBspaFin6WvGKFRYKZgqGCtYKJgoWCpY/AcA)

### Explanation

```
-/@(^~*]!0{])],i.@-  Input: n (LHS), k (RHS)
                  -  Negate k
               i.@   Range [k-1, k-2, ..., 0]
             ]       Get RHS
              ,      Join, forms [k, k-1, ..., 0]
   (        )        Dyad between n (LHS), [k, k-1, ..., 0] (RHS)
           ]           Get RHS
         0{            Select value at index 0
       ]               Get RHS
        !              Binomial coefficient
    ^~                 Raise each in RHS to power of n
      *                Multiply
-/@                  Reduce from right to left using subtraction (forms alternating sum)
```

Comment: `-/@(^~*]!0{])]-i.`

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
#`¦ḣ¹π²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fe2h5arFGsdujpsb/ygmHlj3csfjQzvMNhzb9//8/WsNYx0hTR8NUxxhIWuiYaMYCAA)

#### Explanation

```
#`¦ḣ¹π²  Inputs: n (²), implicit k (¹)
     π²  Cartesian power of [1..k] to n
#        Count if:
   ḣ¹      Range [1..k]
 `¦        Is a subset
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>56 53</s> 50 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k:n/k and(1/k or f(n-1,k-1)+f(n-1,k))*k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcnBDkAwEATQM1@xxy4rsi4SiY@pUFZZ0rj4@tLEwWVm8ua8r@XQJkbXb3YfRgtKvtPag9XR8NtHAGe0YvIVY/lNxMJH914CohCszpNharHLs6TrX6Xk5NkZRC8jtJJLiRgf)

-3 bytes thanks to H.PWiz.

-3 bytes thanks to Dennis.

- If `n<k` not all `k` can be mapped onto thus there are no surjections. `n/k and` takes care of this.
- Taking `f(0,0)=1` gives us the only nonzero base case we need. `1/k or` achieves this.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 49 bytes

```r
function(n,k,j=0:k)((-1)^(k-j)*j^n)%*%choose(k,j)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPJ1sny9bAKltTQ0PXUDNOI1s3S1MrKy5PU1VLNTkjP784VQOoQvN/moaljoXmfwA)

Implements one of the formulas by Mario Catalani:

```r
T(n, k) = Sum_{j=0..k} (-1)^(k-j)*j^n*binomial(k, j)
```

or alternately:

```r
T(n, k) = Sum_{j=0..k} (-1)^j*binomial(k, j)*(k-j)^n
```

which yields the same byte count in R.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 46 bytes

```ruby
f=->n,k{k>n ?0:k+n<1?1:k*(f[n-=1,k]+f[n,k-1])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcm9CoAgFEDhvacQWvq5gtc0TLIeJFwaXC5IBA0RPbuZ2/k457XfKQXHlwj00BLZKiz1ccYVLXVN2CJ3COT7XEAcffumg4VtAOlZPVZ/axhyoxZFBlSWEkaq4gnMf5VGLUX6AA)

Standard recursive approach...

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 142 bytes

```
({}<({}()){({}[(())]<<>{({}({})<>)<>}{}>)}{}>)<>{<>(({}<>)<{({}[()]<([])({([{}]()({}))([{}]({}))}{}[{}])>)}{}({}<>)>)<>}<>{}{}{({}<>[{}])<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxDoAwCER/xREGd00IP9J0qIOJ0Ti4Er4dD5pQ@ji4O75xvev5jDuCzAWPmA1fI0AX0RxQLIpyc@VqWIhSesDTgHNqncmomXfidPHkJNiSuQKmsSKRBMFKqYPSIvZl@wE)

This uses the standard inclusion-exclusion formula.

I can't write up a full explanation at this time, but here's a high-level explanation:

```
# Compute k-th row of Pascal's triangle
({}<({}()){({}[(())]<<>{({}({})<>)<>}{}>)}{}>)<>

# Multiply each element by n^j (and reverse to other stack)
{<>(({}<>)<{({}[()]<([])({([{}]()({}))([{}]({}))}{}[{}])>)}{}({}<>)>)<>}

# Compute alternating sum
<>{}{}{({}<>[{}])<>}<>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 38 bytes

```
(n,k)->Pol(exp(x+O(x^n))-1)^k*n!\x^n%x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcdBCoMwEEDRq4yCMGMnC1HBLuoV7F4jhFJFDOkgLsbTp3H13xd3bGaVuLwiBt7J9O@fx68K6mNAnQORqWjey5BN6QqNTsRfqGB6kGMLZ2J@Tw4f5z0uDErEMI4tQ20TOobm7pOhs5biHw)

Using the formula by Vladimir Kruchinin on OEIS:

```
E.g.f.: (exp(x)-1)^k = sum T(n,k)x^n/n!
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 43 bytes

```javascript
T=(n,k)=>n<k?0:k+n<1||k*(T(--n,k)+T(n,k-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XctBDsIgEEDRfU/CCBhASKgBvQQXaCppWprBWOOKuyMsdf3@36bPdMyv9fnmmB@x1uAJsgT@hi7dxTVRdLKUdCKBcN6Fhh5wCVDnjEfe43nPS2PDLuC9NAKGX7BMN9DCKv1PI7P90UYaJaB@AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
sLsãʒêgQ}g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/2Kf48OJTkw6vSg@sTf//35TLGAA)

**Explanation**

```
sLsã       # Cartesian product of range(k) repeated n times
    ʒ   }  # Filter by ...
     êgQ   # Connected uniquified length == k  (every item in range(k) appears at least once)
         g # Count
```